# Form blocks don't stack upon each other

Tags: html, css, forms

In my form I've got 2 input buttons. Each've got 100% width so they should stack upon each other, but they not. They have width 50%. Why?

HTML

```
<form>
 <div class="input">
    <input type="text" class="button" id="email" name="email" placeholder="YOUR EMAIL"/>
    <input type="submit" class="button" id="submit" value="SUBSCRIBE"/>
 </div>      
</form>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background-color: yellow;
}

form {
    max-width: 450px;
    margin: 17% auto; }
form .input {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; }
form .input:focus {
    outline: none;
    outline: 2px solid #E86C8D;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #E86C8D; }
form .button {
    height: 44px;
    border: none;
    width: 100%; }
form #email {
    background: #FDFCFB;
    font-family: inherit;
    color: #737373;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-indent: 5%;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px; }
form #submit {
    height: 46px;
    background: #E86C8D;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: inherit;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out; }
form #submit:hover {
    background: #d45d7d; }
```

http://codepen.io/Shalahmander/pen/yMJmBZ?editors=1100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: flex` aligns the child elements in a row by default. Add `flex-direction: column` to your `form .input` class to get them to display in a column, i.e. stacked on top of each other.

```css
body {
  background-color: yellow;
}

form {
    max-width: 450px;
    margin: 17% auto; 
}
form .input {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center; 
}
form .input:focus {
    outline: none;
    outline: 2px solid #E86C8D;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #E86C8D; 
}
form .button {
    height: 44px;
    border: none;
    width: 100%; 
}
form #email {
    background: #FDFCFB;
    font-family: inherit;
    color: #737373;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-indent: 5%;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px; 
}
form #submit {
    height: 46px;
    background: #E86C8D;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: inherit;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out; 
}
form #submit:hover {
    background: #d45d7d; 
}
```

```html
<form>
   <div class="input">
      <input type="text" class="button" id="email" name="email" placeholder="YOUR EMAIL"/>
      <br class="visible-xs">
      <input type="submit" class="button" id="submit" value="SUBSCRIBE"/>
   </div>
</form>
```